# Regex for javascript to test strings, number and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regex to validate a text field in javascript. The condition is that it can contain Characters from a to z (small letters or caps), can include numbers and spaces and the some special characters e.g `()[]’“/.-_&–`
It cannot start with a space or end with a space.

I have written the following

```
([A-Za-z0-9\s*\(\)\[\]'"/.\-_&–])
```

But I am pretty sure it can be improved upon a lot. Can someone help

Comment: what is the actual question? does the regex actually work for what you need? are you looking for alternative (maybe simpler) regex to do the same?

Comment: The question is if the community here can tell me a better version of writing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
/^(?! )(?!.* $)[\w *()\[\]'"\/.&–-]+$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JxEBak/2)

**Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?! )`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a space at start
- `(?!.* $)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a space at end
- `[\w *()\[\]'"\/.&-]+`: Match 1+ of the allowed characters
- `$`: End

Note that `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: This fails for the following

`abcdfds(fdsa454Abcv)[das]12345 fdaAAFBVD'"/.-_&–fds fdsa`

Comment: That was due to unicode hyphen `–`, btw your accepted answer doesn't accept `a` or `ab` or `12` (anything below 3 characters in length) - Check my updated answer now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 2):

```
^[^\s][\w\s\(\)\[\]\'\"\/\.\-\&\–]+[^\s]$
```

- `^` - start
- `[^\s]` - no white space
- `[\w\s\(\)\[\]\'\"\/\.\-\&\–]+` - at least one of those characters (\w means [a-zA-Z0-9_])
- `[^\s]` - no white space
- `$` - end

Comment: @anubhava is right and his answer is the correct one - my solution requires the input to be at least 3 characters long. you should accept his answer

Comment: Thank you very much